# Entry point after logging in using securesocial module

Tags: playframework

When a user logs in through one of the providers in SecureSocial module, does control return to any user written controller from SecureSocial?

Upon successful login, if the local database needs to be updated and a different view needs to be rendered, how can that be accomplished?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When the user gets authenticated it will call your UserService.save() method implementation.  At that point you can save/update or do anything you need in the database.

As of redirections, the way SecureSocial works is by intercepting requests to the controllers annotated with the SecureSocial.class.  SecureSocial will redirect to the url the user tried to access before being authenticated.  If you have other needs you could add a @Before interceptor in your own controllers and decide what to do from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Jorge.
I was able to get the interception based control in the controller. I then check if user exists and then update the database if new user.
However I did not understand the .save() that needs to be implemented. Do we need to a create a class which extends securesocial.SecureSocial?

Comment: If you plan to persist users you need to provide your own implementation of the UserService.Service interface.  SecureSocial comes with a default implementation that only stores things in memory and is not suitable for a production environment.  Please check the javadocs of the UserService.Service interface for more info.

Comment: @Jorge can you please provide sample code to save a user in h2 memory database which can be seen in h2-browser?

Comment: @NehaChoudhary I don't have a sample to save the user in h2 but the sample app comes with a UserService implementation that stores things in a hash map.  That should work as a guide for your implemetation. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Jorge I made a my own User class which is an entity and I made a UserId class also. The UserId class is necessary or the UserId class of secureSocial would work. But to get it work I have to write it with Embeddable annotation, right?
and When I try to extend BaseUserService then my derived class becomes inconsistent, the exact error is "The hierarchy of the type InDatabaseUserService is inconsistent".
and out of curiousity, can this module be made into only java(no scala)?

Comment: @NehaChoudhary the module is written in Scala but is totally usable in Java. I provided APIs in both languages for it.  As of the clases you want to persist you can do anything you want there.  The idea is that the UserService implementation will translate back and forth between your model objects and SocialUser which is what SecureSocial understands.  I just released a User Guide at https://www.securesocial.ws.  Check that out.

Comment: @Jorge Thanks for the link, that's now really a true tutorial for securesocial module.